# How manually to set device token ID for firebase cloud messaging?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to set the device token to the UID when a user logs in. Is this possible? If yes How?

Comment: are you using fcm?

Comment: Yes. I'm using FCM

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to set the device token for Firebase Cloud Messaging yourself. It would actually be an anti-pattern to set a user's ID, since the same user may end up using the app on different devices.

If you're trying to send a message to a user (even when that user is on multiple devices), you'll need to associate the device tokens with the UID yourself. I know of a few ways to do this:

1. One way to do that is to combine the tokens into a device group, and then [send a message to that device group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group).
2. Another way would be to store the device tokens for each UID yourself, for example in the Firebase Database or Cloud Firestore, and the loop over them to send a message to all device tokens for a user.
3. The third approach does not require you to manage tokens at all. Instead: create a topic for each user, and have the user subscribe to their own topic. I described this approach in [Sending notifications between Android devices with Firebase Database and Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html). Note that anyone who knows a topic ID can subscribe to that topic, so you should only use this approach for public (but targeted) communication.

Comment: Thank you. From What I can understand, FCM wouldn't be a viable solution for the standard chat app we are used to because of the way the tokens are handled(i.e they keep changing, and instead of being associated to individual users they are associated to devices). Is this accurate? If yes is there a better SDK that can be used to exchange messages between users?

Comment: For solution on I noticed that If it is the case that the user was active in more than one device, and now is only active in one, we'll have an array of active tokens that we'll be sending messages to when we don't have to.

Comment: @vanderouana firebase is best for chat Apps because of its realtime database